# What's the difference between "what are you waiting for" & "what do you waiting for"?

Tags: grammar, difference

What's the difference between "what are you waiting for" and "what do you waiting for"?

Thank you!

Comment: "What do you waiting for?" isn't grammatical. Can you tell a little more about where you found these sentences?

Comment: Thank you, I guess I made a mistake, I will not use what do you waiting for again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What do you waiting for?" is ungrammatical; however, "What do you wait for?" is okay.

"What are you waiting for?" is present tense – if someone asks me that question, they are assuming I am waiting for something, and are asking what it is I am waiting for:

> *What are you waiting for*?
>   I am waiting for the train to come by.

"What do you wait for?" is asking about something that is ongoing:

> *Every day I see you standing here, as if you're waiting for something. What do you wait for?*
>   I wait for the train to pass by.

One other thing: "What are you waiting for?" is sometimes used as a [rhetorical question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question), asking essentially the same thing as, "Why are you just standing there?"

> *Billy, I need you to go out and rake the leaves.*
>   Billy [not moving]: "Okay."
>   *Well, what are you waiting for?*

The phrase "What do you wait for?" would not be used in this context.